# Можно ли заставить InlelliJ IDEA автоматически менять значение переменной?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, дата

Пишу код на *php* с использованием *IntelliJ IDEA*.

У меня есть переменная 
`$last_edit_date = '27_04_16';`

Необходимо после любого изменения в этом файле автоматически проставлять дату в этой переменной (можно в любом формате). Сам я могу про это через пару месяцев забыть.

Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы это работало и при изменении других файлов в проекте?

Comment: нет, это нереально в плане идеи. А чем тебе php скрипт не устраивает, который берет дату последнего изменения файла методами из коробки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea не должна такими вещами заниматься, да она и не может. Она лишь помогает редактировать код, а сами операции (особенно такие) можно делать через сам интерпритатор. Idea лишь обертка.

Доки:

**Метод:** [filemtime](http://www.php.su/functions/?filemtime)

**Пример из дока:**

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt'; // можно указать на текущий через __FILE__
if (file_exists($filename)) { // проверяешь на существование
    echo "в последний раз файл $filename был изменен: " . 
        date ("d.m.Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename)); // выведет дату в таком формате d.m.Y H:i:s
}
```

Comment: Классно. Не додумался до этого :) Спасибо большое.